# PDF Blob not saving with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have this code:

```
$.post('/pdf/render', params, function (data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = downloadUrl;
    a.download = "results.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}):
```

Once my PDF downloads, the clicked URL and blob saves my PDF with the correcct number of pages, but there is nothing in the PDF.  Am I doing something wrong with my blob?  Why would there be no content when I am getting the content from the backend?

For clairfication, I checked with cURL and got a proper PDF with content.

Comment: For what I see, your code should work. Could you do `console.log(data)` to see if your data is fetched from your server?

Comment: whats in the `data` ?

Comment: data contains a PDF file, and I do get it correctly from the server in a console.log.

Comment: @psion, are you doing the `console.log` in your frontend or in your backend?

Comment: @edkeveked frontend.

Comment: If you try to clean up your revoke the anchor after download: `URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);`. I am not sure if that will change something, but you can try. Also don't forget to remove one of the duplicate statements `var a = document.createElement("a");` You can also consider changing your `post` method to `get`